# Set zoom level for tile map in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tiles, zoom

How can set zoom level scale for tile map?

I want set zoom level scale like google map.

Set zoom level according to tiles.

Comment: This may or may not be useful for you: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/03/19/how-can-you-tell-what-map-scales-are-shown-for-online-maps/

Comment: @PolyGeo I try it but the number of scale is different to google map